# How to force Android decoder to decode frame to RGB

Tags: android, rgb, android-mediacodec, yuv, color-space

Do manufacturers force the color format on their hardware decoders? It seems that Android MediaCodec decodes a frame to YUV on Nexus 7 and 9. Is there any way to force the color format for the decoded frame to be RGB instead? Why do manufacturers have proprietary color formats (as is the case with Nexus 7's Qualcomm)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The YUV color formats that the hardware decoders use are more efficient.
For example, a frame in YUV420 is half the size of the same frame in RGB.

Comment: I understand it is more efficient but is it possible to output RGB instead?

Comment: every codec have its own list of supported color formats. I never saw an android codec with RGB support.

Comment: So you think it is unlikely as a supported feature?

Comment: Yes. __________